# Qrcode generate by id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, qr-code

i have qrcode but in there i have trouble. in my app i want my qrcode can auto generate by id.my code work but the exiting not make qrcode but only show code text. can someone tell me how to fix it ?

so, there is my view :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 code">
     {!! QrCode::size(250)->generate('<?php echo $row->name?>'); !!}
     <p>Scan for locations.</p>
</div>
```

and this my controller,  :

```
public function getEdit($id)  {
        $data['row'] = locations::find($id);
        return view('locations_form',$data);
    }

    public function postEditSave($id) {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['name']=Request::input('name');
        $simpan['id_cms_companies']=Request::input('id_cms_companies');

        DB::table('locations')->where('id', $id)->update($simpan);
        Session::flash('edit', 'Data berhasil di Edit');
        return Redirect::to('locations');
    }
```

and this my table :
[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code. Try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 code">
     {!! QrCode::size(250)->generate($row->name) !!}
     <p>Scan for locations.</p>
</div>
```

Everything inside `{!! !!}` is PHP and you don't need to use `<?php echo $var ?>` here.